# Detect cell format change

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How can I detect a change in the fill colour of a cell in a column in a table, I have tried using OnChange like;

```
Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
......
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.ListObjects("tbl_City").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
```

but that does not seem to work for changes to formatting. Is there a way to detect a change in the cell value and/or its fill.

Comment: Would you like to delete entire row or the cell only,, and any specific colored cell or any color ?

Comment: Please [edit] your post & be clear that you want to remove the Cell format or Cell content has cell format (Fill color) !!

Answer (score 0):

There are no events that can be triggered when the cell format type changes.

The conditions that are triggered are generally changes in values.

As a workaround, you can capture the selection action to get the cell's pre-change state, whenever a cell is selected you grab the format and address of that cell as well as check the address and format of the previous cell VS what the format of the previous cell is now. thus, if the format of the previous cell is different now than it was when last captured, it has been changed.

You can refer to this similar situation below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342408/how-to-detect-changes-in-cell-format